# Encrypt IP payload + URL

Tags: encryption, vpn, ssl, tor, private-network

I need to encrypt IP payload + request URL so that my ISP can't understand my requests. Do you know any project such as `zebedee` except VPNs?

Tor doesn't work with my ISP, because SSL was banned, so systems corresponding to Socks don't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try Tor's obfsproxy. It was specifically designed for this kind of usecases. It obfuscates the traffic between the client and a Tor bridge in a way, that - in theory - it becomes indistinguishable from gibberish. At least it shouldn't be triggered as Tor- or SSL-traffic.

https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy.html.en

Answer (score 3):

You can't have your cake and eat it. Your ISP carries the network traffic from your computer to the server, so it has to know which host the traffic is going to. Note that if you use HTTPS, the ISP knows which host you're connecting to, it doesn't see the rest of the URL.

If you don't want your ISP to know which server you're connecting to, you need to relay all your connections through an external proxy. That way all your ISP has to know is that your traffic is going to the proxy.

If your ISP is blocking some traffic, there's always a way to tunnel it somehow. It's a cat-and-mouse game: if your ISP blocks something, encode your traffic inside something else. For example, you can use [httptunnel](http://www.nocrew.org/software/httptunnel.html) to encode IP traffic inside HTTP.

Comment: `httptunnel`? A toy. People've written [DNS tunnels](http://dnstunnel.de/) and [ping tunnels](http://freecode.com/projects/ptunnel). *That's* impressive. :)

Comment: @WarrenYoung Impressive, sure. Passes firewalls, not so much. Many places block all ICMP, and sometimes only the web proxy can use DNS.